# Rails Devise User has multiple actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise

Preface:  New to Rails, and a novice programmer, be gentle ;)

My question is so broad, I can't seem to hone in on a strategy here, so maybe one of you can help.  I can set up user authentication no problem, used Devise - was surprised how easy it was.

My problem is that I need to understand the basic strategy for this:  I want to have these Users, who can perform two basic actions.  1) Make a Request.  2) Fulfill A Request.

So, conceptually, a user can be both a "requester" or a "fulfiller of requests," at anytime.

I started to set this up, and halfway through realized I need to slow down and plan, but I got stuck wondering what the best way to do this is.  A "fulfill" needs to be linked to a specific "request" from a specific "user."

If someone can just point me in the right direction, even some documentation related to this type of thing, I would be very grateful.

I am familiar with the concept of a model that has_many and belongs_to, and assume that's going to be a part of a solution here, but not sure how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: just some clarification:  I think what I really need to figure out here, is do I need 3 models, (User, Request, Fulfill), or just User, and Request, and have the Request be "fulfillable" ?

Comment: If some of the users will post requests and a different set, which might intersect with 'posters', will fulfill the request, you'll need to apply roles to your users. For example 'requestor' and 'fulfiller'. If you want to go through the roles path, then your answer is here http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/. Otherwise, if you don't need roles, I think the answer is to have 3 models, as you suggested.

Comment: i didn't know about the concept of roles, thanks for the link, digesting it right now - not 100% sure yet if roles is the answer or not, but looks promising so far, thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Devise manages your authentication, now you need to manage your authorisation with roles - take a look at CanCan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan and https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-with-CanCan-for-roles-management for integration instructions